# What does this kafka error mean on a shared cluster setup and how to resolve this?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs

I have been using the shared cluster setup for some time now to test some stuff on **CloudKarafka**. It gave me no problems until yesterday when I started getting this error message.

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2019-09-23T21:24:47.812Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Metadata(key: 3, version: 4)","broker":"velomobile-01.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094","clientId":"kafkajs",**"error":"There is no leader for this topic-partition as we are in the middle of a leadership election"**,"correlationId":8,"size":333}

{ KafkaJSNumberOfRetriesExceeded
Caused by: KafkaJSProtocolError: There is no leader for this topic-partition as we are in the middle of a leadership election<br />
.
.
name: 'KafkaJSNumberOfRetriesExceeded', retriable: false, helpUrl: undefined, originalError:
{ KafkaJSProtocolError: There is no leader for this topic-partition as we are in the middle of a leadership election.
```

I am using npm module kafkajs for a node application with no config changes lately. Is there something wrong with my shared instance? Any suggestions to try.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried with a new instance on shared cluster and also a new user on cloudkarafka with instance in new region, but nothing worked. Got the same error.